# Return variable type along an enum c++

Tags: c++, types, enums, return, constexpr

I needed it for a socket buffer that I'm making (reading and writing...), this is more a trick than anything else so I would like to know if there is a better way of doing it with the current c++ features/standards? I'm sure of it.

```
enum e_Types
{
    Type_64 ,
    Type_32 ,
    Type_16 ,
    Type_8 ,
    Type_ALL
};

template<e_Types Type> constexpr auto _GetVarType()
{
    if constexpr( Type == Type_8 )
        return ( unsigned char* ) 0;
    if constexpr( Type == Type_16 )
        return ( unsigned short* ) 0;
    if constexpr( Type == Type_32 )
        return ( unsigned long* ) 0;
    if constexpr( Type == Type_64 )
        return ( unsigned long long* ) 0;
}

#define GetVarType(type) decltype( _GetVarType<type>() )
```

Example:

```
GetVarType( Type_64 ) p64 = malloc(0x1000);
```

Thanks for replies.

Comment: how about [cstdint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)? or the `e_Types` are necessary?

Comment: names starting with `_` and upper letter are reserved on all namespaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use good old explicit template class specialization:

```
template <e_Types X> struct type_of;
template <>          struct type_of<Type_64> { using type = unsigned long long; };
template <>          struct type_of<Type_32> { using type = unsigned long; };
template <>          struct type_of<Type_16> { using type = unsigned short; };
template <>          struct type_of<Type_8>  { using type = unsigned char; };

template <e_Types X> 
using type_of_t = typename type_of<X>::type;
```

Usage:

```
type_of_t<Type_64>* p64 = malloc(0x1000);
```

---

If you want to go down the `constexpr`-based route, you can do something like:

```
template <typename T> 
struct type_wrapper 
{ 
    using type = T; 
};

template <typename T> 
inline constexpr type_wrapper<T> t{};

template <e_Types X> inline constexpr auto type_of          = t<void>;
template <>          inline constexpr auto type_of<Type_64> = t<unsigned long long>;
template <>          inline constexpr auto type_of<Type_32> = t<unsigned long>;
template <>          inline constexpr auto type_of<Type_16> = t<unsigned short>;
template <>          inline constexpr auto type_of<Type_8>  = t<unsigned char>;
```

Usage:

```
typename decltype(type_of<Type_64>)::type* p64 = malloc(0x1000);
```

But I don't find this superior to the more traditional approach.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: OP's own approach is also ok, though a little ugly. Just replace the macro by  `template<int N> using get_var_type = decltype(_GetVarType<N>());`

Comment: @liliscent: it's OK as in "it works", but I don't see why you would want to use that over template specialization.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo One possible advantage is `if constexpr` could be more expressive for more complicated condition.

Comment: There's a cast missing from the result of `malloc` :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @liliscent and @VittorioRomeo replies/comments,
I ended up to do this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Type_Wrapper
{
    using Type = T;
};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr Type_Wrapper<T> _Type{};

template <e_Types Type> inline constexpr auto _GetVarType()
{
    if constexpr( Type == Type_8 )
        return _Type<Byte>;
    else if constexpr( Type == Type_16 )
        return _Type<Word>;
    else if constexpr( Type == Type_32 )
        return _Type<HEX32>;
    else if constexpr( Type == Type_64 )
        return _Type<HEX64>;
    else if constexpr( Type == Type_Pointer )
        return _Type<Pointer>;
    else if constexpr( Type == Type_Size )
        return _Type<size_t>;
    else if constexpr( Type == Type_Array )
        return _Type<Bytes>;
    else
        return _Type<void>;
};

template<e_Types _Type>
using GetVarType_t = typename decltype( _GetVarType<_Type>() );
```

...

```
GetVarType_t< Type_64 >::Type Ok = 0;
```

It's good now, I wanted to get rid off those 0 cuz it didn't look good.
Thanks again!